# How to add additional PHP versions to EasyPHP DevServer

Tags: easyphp, easyphp-devserver, easyphp-webserver

I have EasyPHP DevServer 17 up and running on my Windows 10 machine. I currently have my EasyPHP environment installed within my `C:\EasyPHP` directory.  I can see from the server settings that I have two options for selecting my PHP verions:

`5.6.30 x86` and `7.1.3 x86`

How can I add a third option to the list? for PHP `7.3 x86`?

- Do I have to re-install an entirely new instance of EasyPHP DevServer to make this happen?
- Can I simply download a thread-safe PHP7.X package online and stick it somewhere in the eds-binaries directory and restart?

I have made several attempts, but all result in failure. What would be the best technical steps?

Thanks!